# How to implement MVC Pattern in Swift using network api call?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller

I want to download data from network. For example downloading an image and name of author.After downloading I want to show it in UITableview.How I will create model for my network class and how I will  store server response in model class like image and name of author.

How this can be achieved with MVC Pattern?

Comment: this is a bad place for this question, you have a lot of tutorials about that.
Create some API manager class and from controller call that api method to get what you need. Then just with the result update view

Comment: I know this but I am not getting proper solution for this.. I just want to consume an api with mvc .. If you have some references regarding my problem.Please share the url.

Comment: do you have any attempts to do that? you will never do that if you do not even try. I will not google for you

Comment: Controller.swift -> which will hold Tableview. Entity.swift -> It will be your model.  ApiManager -> Which will call web service, and here you can parse the data and Set to model, And you can then notify it to your controller.

Comment: Thanks Wolverine..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my tutorial project that fetches images from instagram, stores them in models and displays in a `UICollectionView` (very similar to `UITableView`), you can find it [here](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftIntro)

The project uses [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to fetch data.

Some of the relevant code:

```
class LoadingDataVC: UIViewController, Configurable {

    //MARK: Variables
    @IBOutlet weak var loadingLabel: UILabel!

    var config: GameConfiguration!
    fileprivate var cards: Cards?

    var apiClient: APIClientProtocol!
    var imageCache: ImageCacheProtocol!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    //MARK: VC Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
        fetchData()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: Any?) {
        guard let vc = segue?.destination as? GameVC else { return }
        vc.config = config
        vc.cards = cards
    }
}

private extension LoadingDataVC {

    func fetchData() {
        apiClient.getPhotos(config.username) {
            result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Failed to get photos, error: \(error.description)")
            case .success(let model):
                self.setupWithModel(model.first)
            }
        }
    }

    func setupWithModel(_ model: Cards?) {
        guard let model = model else { return }
        let singles = model.singles
        self.cards = Cards(singles, config: config)
        prefetchImagesForCards(singles)
    }

    func prefetchImagesForCards(_ cards: [Card]) {
        let urls: [URL] = cards.map { return $0.imageUrl }
        imageCache.prefetchImages(urls) {
            self.startGame()
        }
    }

    func startGame() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: startGameSegue, sender: self)
    }
}

class MemoryDataSourceAndDelegate: NSObject {

    fileprivate let cards: Cards
    fileprivate let gameLevel: Level
    fileprivate weak var delegate: GameDelegate?
    fileprivate let imageCache: ImageCacheProtocol

    init(_ cards: Cards,
           level: Level,
           delegate: GameDelegate,
           imageCache: ImageCacheProtocol
        ) {
        self.cards = cards
        self.gameLevel = level
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.imageCache = imageCache
    }
}

//MARK: Game play Methods
private extension MemoryDataSourceAndDelegate {

    func cardAt(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Card? {
        guard indexPath.row < cards.count else { return nil }
        let index = indexWith(indexPath)
        let model = cards[index]
        return model
    }

    func indexWith(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
        let numberOfItemsInSection = gameLevel.columnCount
        let index = indexPath.row + (numberOfItemsInSection * indexPath.section)
        return index
    }
}

//MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource Methods
extension MemoryDataSourceAndDelegate: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return gameLevel.columnCount
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return gameLevel.rowCount
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CardCVCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

//MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate Methods
extension MemoryDataSourceAndDelegate: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard cardAtIndexPathAlreadyMatched(indexPath) == false else { return }
        didSelectCard(at: indexPath, in: collectionView)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = cell as? CardCVCell else { return }
        guard let model = cardAt(indexPath) else { return }
        let cachedImage = imageCache.imageFromCache(model.imageUrl)
        cell.configure(with: model, image: cachedImage)
    }
}
```